# What does monitor brightness spec refer to?

Tags: display, specifications

I read some monitor specifications, and a brightness value of e.g. 250 cd/m² is often mentioned there. But the monitor can have different brightness settings, and RGB channels can be adjusted to change the final brightness (e.g. RGB all max is one brightness, all min is another).

So, when I read in a specification that a monitor's brightness is 250 cd/m² — what monitor configuration does this refer to? Maximum possible brightness? 50% in all settings? Factory defaults? Or does this spec item simply say that the monitor is *able* to output this brightness, in an unspecified configuration mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What monitor configuration does this refer to?

This pretty much impossible to answer (unless the monitor spec specifies **how** it was measured). Here is why:

> **How is brightness calculated?**
>
> In order to measure brightness of a display, you need something on the
> screen. In most cases, display brightness is measured when the screen
> is showing a full-white image, from edge to edge, top to bottom. For
> displays like LCD displays, that require a light source from behind
> the liquid crystal component, this kind of full-white measurement will
> tell you what maximum light output the display is capable of. Although
> it is unlikely that a customer would how a full-white image on the
> screen, which is the brightest the display will measure.
>
> For emissive displays (like plasma, OLED, or direct view LED), the
> calculation is a little more difficult. Because each pixel is
> addressed directly (and turned on or off depending on the content
> directed to that pixel), the brightness of each pixel will vary as the
> power to drive the pixels is shared among all of the pixels on the
> display. For instance, if you put up a total white field on a emissive
> display, that brightness measurement will be less than if you put up a
> small white square in the middle of a display. One is the standard
> brightness measurement (say “typical”) and one is a peak brightness
> measurement.
>
> **This makes the question “how bright is this display” a bit of a trick question.** It depends on the measurements, of course, but also
> what kind of display technology you are evaluating and what content is
> being shown on the screen when the measurement is taken.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source [How is brightness calculated? | Planar](https://www.planar.com/blog/2017/3/30/how-is-brightness-calculated/)

#### Further Reading

- [How We Test Brightness & Contrast on Monitors & Televisions (TomsHardware)](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/display-monitor-tv-screen-test,3901-2.html)

Answer (score -1):

Monitor Brightness or Luminance is a measurement of the amount of light the
LCD monitor is calibrated to produce.
It is given in nits or one
[candela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela)
per square meter (cd/m2). (And yes, candela does relate to candle light!)

This is a setting that you may normally be able to adjust in the monitor's
on-screen configuration menu (for monitors that show it).

For the sake of a clear picture and reducing eye-strain, you should match the
brightness of your screen to to your surroundings.

If the monitor is set brighter than the room, your eyes get tired and the picture
may look weird (excessive contrast/clipping, color temperature shift).
If the monitor is too dark in a bright room, the picture gets washed out and you
can't see what's on the screen.

The maximum brightness of a monitor is one of the attributes that you may wish
to consider when buying a monitor, in view of the anticipated light in the
environment and your main usage.
For example, for displaying movies, a brighter luminance rating is desirable.

While the monitor can be calibrated to a given brightness,
the effective brightness of the monitor may be further affected by parameters
of the operating system.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question: what the value given in specification actually refers to.

Comment: As written above, it refers to the number of [candelas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela) that the screen is calibrated to produce. This last link contains the mathematical formula used to calculate this value. The monitor's luminosity is measured in the [Candela per square metre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela_per_square_metre), and this is what this value refers to.

Comment: Well, I do know what candela is, and what luminance is. The question is what actual property of the monitor the spec gives: luminance at maximum brightness setting, luminance at factory defaults, luminance at some unspecified settings etc..

Comment: The spec relates to the amount of power that is furnished to the pixels, which determines their brightness. The technology varies by screen type, but basically a pixel achieves more brightness by staying on for longer stretches and using more power. Normally the pixels blink faster than the human eye can catch and the percentage of time on determines the brightness. I can't find a good reference but maybe [this](http://led-displays-china.com/learnCenter/fullcolor-brightness_403.html) might help.